Just installed C Compilers on windows and tried to run a simple program, but result in a seg fault?
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

I am trying to run this code:
When I do
g++ -o test1 test.cpp and then .\test1.exe, nothing gets printed. But the program seems to compile fine.
When I go via vs code, Run C/C++ file, it picks up a seg faults in the first line of the main function, why, how? I'm confused, is there a mistake with my installation somewhere?

this is not C code. C and C++ are two different languages. There is no language called C/C++

What documentation or other resources have you read or followed to install the compiler and VSCode?

Double-click test1.exe in the explorer (the "files" app), tell us what errors it shows.

@Some programmer dude
I followed this guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

@HolyBlackCat No errors, just opens a terminal then closes

This kind of issue can be caused by compiling with the header files for one version of the C++ standard library, but when you run your code you load another version of the C++ standard library. Does that sound plausible? Is there any way you could have multiple versions of the C++ standard library installed?

Interesting. Does g++ -o test1 test.cpp -static work?

@HolyBlackCat yes this works, why does it work?

@john I don't think so, I am setting up C++ for windows for the first time here, before I used to do my c++ programming in WSL, i don't think the 2 should interfere?

@ss123 The fact that static linking works strongly suggests that my theory is right.

Go read this thread: How to debug DLL issues in MinGW?. In short, you need to rearrange your PATH to move the compiler installation to the beginning of it (there are two PATHs, per-user and system-wide, and you want it to be at the beginning of the latter).

If you're on windows, switch to "visual studio community edition" it is far more user-friendly

Not only is this code invalid C code, it is also invalid Rust code.  I strongly suspect it is also invalid Lisp code.  Probably valid Perl code though.

is there a mistake with my installation somewhere? You seem to have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_hell caused by having an incompatible version of the MinGW runtime installed and likely found in a folder of your OS PATH environment variable before the compatible runtime of your current version of MinGW. This could be from a different version of MinGW installed or it can even be some other software (like AI software) that was compiled using MinGW.

Note that rearranging the path order may fix your current problem but will likely break whatever other program counts on the different library implementation. I find it best to very carefully curate the system path to prevent problems like this before they can become a problem. For example, my development machines in the past often had multiple GCC toolchains installed as I have to support many projects going back a few decades. These days I've mostly split the projects up into their own development virtual machine, but that was done more to reduce the cost of spinning up new PCs.
